# How to get attribute value from magento compare list?

Tags: product, product-list, compare

First of all thanks for your help, until now I never needed to write anything here, but I wasn't able to find any answer to this.

I have a compare list in a Magento Store and I want to compare all the items with the same 'name' attribute.

In other words, when I click to the comparison button to add the Product X, I want to see all the products with the same NAME as Product X in the comparison list.

Anyonw knows how to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite the `Mage_Catalog_Product_CompareController::addAction` and when a product is added add the ones with the same name.
for this you need to add this after `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_compare_list')->addProduct($product);`

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
    ->addAttributeToFilter('name', $product->getName())
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('neq' => $product->getId())); //exclude the product that was just added;
//get only available products
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);

//get the product ids
$ids = $collection->getAllIds();
if (count($ids) > 0) {
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_compare_list')->addProducts($ids);
}
```

Comment: Marvelous, thanks so much for your help! :)